# Using spark dataframe transpose

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to figure out how to solve this use case using spark dataframe.

In the below google sheet, I have the source data where the questions from the survey answered by the people will be stored. Also the question columns will be more than 1000 columns approx, and is more dynamic and not fixed.

There is a metadata table, which explains about the question, its description and the choices it can contain.

Output table should be the like the one I had mentioned in the sheet. Any suggestions or ideas on how this can be achieved ?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BAY8XWaio1DbzcQeQgru6PuNfT9A7Uhf650x_-PAjqo/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your main table is called `df`:

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+------+------+------+
|survey_id|response_id|person_name|Q1D102|Q1D103|Q1D105|
+---------+-----------+-----------+------+------+------+
|xyz      |xyz        |john       |1     |2     |1     |
|abc      |abc        |foo        |3     |1     |1     |
|def      |def        |bar        |2     |2     |2     |
+---------+-----------+-----------+------+------+------+
```

and the mapping table is called `df2`:

```
+-----------+-------------+-------------------+---------+-----------+
|question_id|question_name|question_text      |choice_id|choice_desc|
+-----------+-------------+-------------------+---------+-----------+
|Q1D102     |Gender       |What is your gender|1        |Male       |
|Q1D102     |Gender       |What is your gender|2        |Female     |
|Q1D102     |Gender       |What is your gender|3        |Diverse    |
|Q1D103     |Age          |What is your age   |1        |20 - 50    |
|Q1D103     |Age          |What is your age   |2        |50 >       |
|Q1D105     |work_status  |Do you work        |1        |Yes        |
|Q1D105     |work_status  |Do you work        |2        |No         |
+-----------+-------------+-------------------+---------+-----------+
```

We can construct a dynamic unpivot expression as below:

```
val columns = df.columns.filter(c => c.startsWith("Q1D"))

val data = columns.map(c => s"'$c', $c").mkString(",")

val finalExpr = s"stack(${columns.length}, $data) as (question_id, choice_id)"
```

With 3 questions, we get the following expression (`Q1D102`, `Q1D103` and `Q1D105`): `stack(3, 'Q1D102', Q1D102,'Q1D103', Q1D103,'Q1D105', Q1D105) as (question_id, choice_id)`

Finally, we use the constructed variable:

```
df = df
  .selectExpr("survey_id", "response_id", "person_name", finalExpr)
  .join(df2, Seq("question_id", "choice_id"), "left")
```

You get this result:

```
+-----------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------------+-----------+
|question_id|choice_id|survey_id|response_id|person_name|question_name|question_text      |choice_desc|
+-----------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------------+-----------+
|Q1D102     |1        |xyz      |xyz        |john       |Gender       |What is your gender|Male       |
|Q1D102     |2        |def      |def        |bar        |Gender       |What is your gender|Female     |
|Q1D102     |3        |abc      |abc        |foo        |Gender       |What is your gender|Diverse    |
|Q1D103     |1        |abc      |abc        |foo        |Age          |What is your age   |20 - 50    |
|Q1D103     |2        |xyz      |xyz        |john       |Age          |What is your age   |50 >       |
|Q1D103     |2        |def      |def        |bar        |Age          |What is your age   |50 >       |
|Q1D105     |1        |xyz      |xyz        |john       |work_status  |Do you work        |Yes        |
|Q1D105     |1        |abc      |abc        |foo        |work_status  |Do you work        |Yes        |
|Q1D105     |2        |def      |def        |bar        |work_status  |Do you work        |No         |
+-----------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------+-------------+-------------------+-----------+
```

Which I think is what you need (just unordered), good luck!

Comment: Hey, thanks much for your answer. I am sorry as i forgot to mention this. In the source table, the question columns will be more than 1000 columns approx, and is more dynamic and not fixed(varies from survey to survey). Hence i was thinking to use transpose, but not sure if that is the right approach.

I will update this information in my question above. thanks.!!

Comment: Do you mean there are 1000+ columns as `Q1D102`, `Q1D103`, `Q1D105`, etc. ?

Comment: yes exactly. it is more than 1000 columns like Q1D102, Q1D103, Q1D105, Q1D106, Q1D107 etc.

Comment: Edited the post, good luck!